# Where could I update Laravel Migration files Foreign key scripts

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

working with Laravel project and need update `titles` table new columns like `employee_id` and create new migration command `php artisan make:migration add_employee_id_to_titles_table --table=titles` and create new migration file like `add_employee_id_to_titles_tables.php` now I need add following foreign key relationship with new columns and the `titles` table

```
 Schema::table('titles', function ($table){
             $table->foreign('employee_id')->references('id')->on('titles')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

my problem is in witch migration files `titles` or new `add_employee_id_to_titles_tables` should I add this scripts?

Comment: in add_employee_id_to_titles_tables file

Answer (score 0):

When you run `php artisan migrate` it checks your database and migrations table and if there is new migration that didn't save it will run.
So you have to write the scripts in a file that has not been executed

Answer (score 0):

First thing why your `employee_id` reference to the same table `title` ID. it should reference to either `employee` table or whatever you're getting this employee_id from.

In order to update your existing `Title` table you need to create a new migration just like you said `php artisan make:migration add_employee_id_to_titles_table --table=titles` and than

```
Schema::table('titles', function ($table){
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('employee_id');
    $table->foreign('employee_id')->references('id')->on('employees')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```